# Using PHP to extract dates in different formats from a string

Tags: php, preg-match, extract

I am using **cURL and WHOIS queries** to retrieve registration information of different Websites.

The problem is the WHOIS queries return strings with dates in different formats.

I would like to use preg_match to **extract the creation date and expiry date** into separate arrays like:

```
$creation = array(year, month, day);
$expiration = array(year, month, day);
```

The different string outputs come in the formats:

```
    expires: 2014-01-10 14:00:27
    created: 2012-01-10 15:00:28

    Creation Date: 25-Mar-2010  
    Expiration Date: 25-Mar-2013

    Record created:     14/04/2012
    Record expires:     14/04/2013

    Record created on.......: Mar 05, 2001  
    Record expires on.......: Mar 05, 2013

    Created on..............: 1997-09-15.
    Expires on..............: 2020-09-13.

    Expiration Date: 2015-12-26 19:18:07
    Creation Date:   2003-12-26 19:18:07
```

Any clues on how to use preg_match to extract the dates?

*Note*: I've tried with PHP Whois API class but it doesn't work well, and different XML APIs but the data is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually worked out this function:

```
function creationdate($data)
{

if(preg_match('/Creation Date:/i',$data) == true){
    $csta = strpos($data, 'Creation Date:', 0)+14;
    $cstb = strpos($data, 'Creation Date:', 0)+27;
    $date = trim(substr($data, $csta, $cstb-$csta));
return strtotime($date);};

if(preg_match('/Record created:/i',$data) == true){
    $csta = strpos($data, 'Record created:', 0)+15;
    $cstb = strpos($data, 'Record expires:', $csta)-2;
    $date = substr($data, $csta, $cstb-$csta);
    $date = explode('/', $date);
    $date = $date[0] .'-'. $date[1] .'-'. $date[2];
return strtotime($date);};

if(preg_match('/Created on..............:(.*?)\./i',$data,$date) == true){
return strtotime($date[1]);};

if(preg_match('/Record created on.......:/i',$data) == true){
    $csta = strpos($data, 'Record created on.......:', 0)+26;
    $cstb = strpos($data, 'Record expires on.......:', $csta)-5;
    $date = substr($data, $csta, $cstb-$csta);
return strtotime($date);};

if(preg_match('/created:/i',$data) == true){
    $csta = strpos($data, 'created:', 0)+9;
    $cstb = strpos($data, 'created:', 0)+20;
    $date = trim(substr($data, $csta, $cstb-$csta));
return strtotime($date);};

return '-';

}
```